# Xamarin.Forms MasterDetail over tab

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've got a problem with Xamarin.Forms on Android. I have a MasterDetailPage with a TabbedPage as the detail and a ContentPage as the master.

My Problem is, that the drawer from the master (the left navbar) is being displayed beneath the tabs of the TabbedPage.

There is no Z-Index in Xamarin.Forms, so how can I fix that without using a custom render or something like that (cause that would destroy the reason for me using xamarin).

Answer (score 1):

Using custom renderers does not defeat the objective of Xamarin.  In fact it is a key feature that adds a huge amount of flexibility and is simply necessary.

I would go as far as to say that very few published Xamarin apps would have no custom renderers at all - since Xamarin only really provide a few key components out of the box.

I think for this, you will indeed need a renderer.